# MicroStrategy Error: Server 'SERVER_NAME' has temporarily become unavailable

Tags: mysql, database, teradata, business-intelligence, microstrategy

I have a Linux SUSE server with Microstrategy 10.3 installed, metadata stored on MySQL database on the same server and I am trying to connect to data stored on Teradata database. The problem is when I create any report or cube and run it; I get the error:

> Error: Server 'SERVER_NAME' has temporarily become unavailable.
>    and the service stops. I attached the DSSErrors log for further information.

Answer (score 0):

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4
[Security Guide](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/singlehtml/book_security/book_security.html)

Linux server [technical data](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips)